# Python Dask - Group-by performance on all columns

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to count the number of unique rows in my data. Below a quick input/output example.

```
#input
A,B
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,0
1,1
1,1

#output
A,B,count
0,0,1
0,1,1
1,0,2
1,1,2
```

The data in my pipeline have more than 5000 columns and more than 1M rows, each cell is a 0 or a 1. Below there are my two attempts at scaling with Dask (with 26 columns):

```
import numpy as np
import string
import time

client = Client(n_workers=6, threads_per_worker=2, processes=True)

columns = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

data = np.random.randint(2, size = (1000000, len(columns)))

ddf_parent = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns), npartitions=20)

#1st solution
ddf = ddf_parent.astype(str)

ddf_concat = ddf.apply(''.join, axis =1).to_frame()

ddf_concat.columns = ['pattern']

ddf_concat = ddf_concat.groupby('pattern').size()

start = time.time()
ddf_concat = ddf_concat.compute()
print(time.time()-start)

#2nd solution
ddf_concat_other = ddf_parent.groupby(list(ddf.columns)).size()

start = time.time()
ddf_concat_other = ddf_concat_other.compute()
print(time.time() - start)
```

results:

```
9.491615056991577
12.688117980957031
```

The first solution first concatenates every column into a string and then runs the group-by on it. The second one just group-by all the columns. I am leaning toward using the first one as it is faster in my tests, but I am open to suggestions. Feel free to completely change my solution if there is anything better in term of performance (also, interesting, sort=False does not speed up the group-by, which may actually be related to this: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5441 and this https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/2717)

NOTE:
After some testing the first solution scales relatively well with the number of columns. I guess one improvement could be to hash the strings to always have a fix length. Any suggestion on the partition number in this case? From the remote dashboard I can see that after couple of operations the nodes in the computational graph reduces to only 3, not taking advantage of the other workers available.

The second solutions fails when columns increase.

NOTE2:
Also, with the first solution, something really strange is happening with what I guess is how Dask schedules and maps operations. What is happening is that after some time a single worker gets many more tasks than the others, then the worker exceed 95% of the memory, crash, then tasks are split correctly, but after some time another worker gets more tasks (and the cycle restart). The pipeline runs fine, but I was wondering if this is the expected behavior. Attached a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: How many unique rows do you expect to have in your full database?

Comment: A lot, that's why in the example the data are randomly generated. I expect at least a third of these rows to be unique (maybe even half). Thanks @kate-melnykova

Comment: If the value of each column is decoded by a single letter or digit, then the first solution is good enough for me. If not, I would change it to `ddf_concat = ddf.apply('_'.join, axis =1).to_frame()`.

Comment: Nice! Thank you @kate-melnykova. Any suggestion on NOTE2?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas there.